# drinfeld shtukas over higher dimensional spaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, shimura-varieties

Everytime I encounter Drinfeld Shtukas, the definition begins with vector bundles over a curve $X$ over a finite field. My question is: why the restriction to curves? Is there any interest or results for the analogues of Drinfeld shtukas over for example surfaces?